# Modeling a Mongodb array using Rails form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am working on an application that has a project model that contains tags. The model roughly looks like:

```
class Project
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :tags, type: Array
  ...
  ...
end
```

I am trying to figure out the best way to make a form for creating/editing a project that would allow a user to add multiple tags. I would like to use rails built-in form_for method, if possible.

The issue I am coming across is that I am unsure how to give the user the ability to add multiple tags.

One idea would be to use a string field, and then before the project is created/updated, I could split the string on comma's, or spaces. I could also easily create a text area and split on a new line character.

However, I would much rather give the user the ability to add tags by typing a value into a field, and then clicking a plus symbol to append it to an array of tags. I can easily accomplish this with javascript, but I was wondering if a solution exists, whether it be through another gem or using an existing rails method, that would not require me to write custom javascript for the form?

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generate an array with params you can do by define a "[]". So you can do :

`text_field_tag "project[tags][]"`